# another way to express "not limited to"

Tags: expression-choice

Not limited to X, the issue also affects Y.

What could substitute "not limited to" other than not restricted to/bounded to?

I overused these words and looking for simple substitutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation, we have the very handy preposition **besides**, meaning:

> : other than (someone or something)
>
> : in addition to (something)

(from Merriam-Webster online)

For example:

> **Besides** impacting air quality, vehicular traffic causes noise pollution.

The relationship between the ideas you've given in your example is one of *addition*, and there is no reason you need to limit yourself to negative expressions, as you've listed. Additional expressions of addition include:

**in addition to**

**together with**

**apart from**

**aside from**

Comment: Don't forget ***as well as***, which might even be the most common of the lot for such contexts. I'd also say that *on average* OP's "inverted" construction wouldn't be so highly favoured. To me, the most succinct *and* most natural form would be *"The issue affects Y as well as X"*.

Comment: The inverted construction suited the context in this case so "and"/"as well as" while simple is not applicable to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple and straightforward:

> Both X and Y are affected by the issue.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is not confined to.